# Unable to retrieve the api token using requests library python

Tags: python, api

I'm trying to use requests API to login into Zabbix API, but unable to do due to the below issue.

I want to achieve the login by pyzabbix module, but I want to use API user authentication token.

Without password and username in the code (any suggestion would help me).

Error:

> json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Code:

```
import requests
from pprint import pprint
import json


url = 'http://127.0.0.1/zabbix'

########################################
# user.login
########################################
payload = {
    "jsonrpc" : "2.0",
    "method" : "user.login",
    "params": {
      'user': 'Admin',
      'password':'Zabbix',
    },
    "auth" : None,
    "id" : 0,
}
headers = {
    'content-type': 'application/json',
}
res  = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
print(res)
res = res.json()
print('user.login response: ',res['result'])
```

Comment: What `status_code` you are getting?

Comment: I think `res` is not json, can you show output for `print(res)` ?

Comment: It also might be an issue of you mixing `'` and `"` in payload, which results in an incorrect request, but indeed, do show `res`, without passing it to json parser.

Comment: print of res is ['200']

Comment: Potentially you need to use `json.loads(res.text)`?

Comment: If you just curl that payload to the URL, what's the actual response? Is it JSON?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call the Zabbix API you have to use the correct endpoint, which is `api_jsonrpc.php`.

So, for instance you can use:

```
url = 'http://127.0.0.1/api_jsonrpc.php'
```

However your code does not account for errors (ie: if Admin/Zabbix is wrong, your script will return a key error, because the error response does not contain a `result`.

A better choice is to use a library such as [py-zabbix](https://pypi.org/project/py-zabbix/)